# Azure Log Analytics Query for Day of the week

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I am trying to build a graph in log analytics workspace to find out what day of the week has the most log ins.

I have this query

```
SigninLogs
| where ResultType ==  0
| summarize SuccessfulSigns=count() by bin(TimeGenerated,1d)
```

But I was wanting to do like a bar graph where you see how many log ins were on Sundays, Mondays Etc for the 90 days its querying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`dayofweek`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/dayofweekfunction) with format_timespan, something like

```
let Days = datatable(day_number:int, day:string)
[
1, "Monday",
2, "Tuesday",
3, "Wednesday",
4, "Thursday",
5, "Friday",
6, "Saturday",
7, "Sunday",
];

SigninLogs
| where ResultType ==  0
| summarize SuccessfulSigns=count() by day_number=toint(format_timespan(dayofweek(bin(TimeGenerated,1d)), "d"))
| join Days on day_number
| project SuccessfulSigns, day
```

That returns the day as integer 1=Monday, 2=Tuesday, 3=Wednesday and maps this to the datatable day_number.

```
day         SuccessfulSigns
Wednesday   135
```

Comment: This is awesome, thank you!

Comment: This is what I need, do you know if you can convert those integers into days of the week? I wanted to put this into a dashboard for my boss to read.

Comment: @Bnd10706 I don't know an easy function to get the right day-name, but you can do it by using a datable, see the edit, hope that helps

Comment: ok I was able to do it using |extend